# How to set z-index for gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is it possible to control the z-index of a new gnome-terminal window? I want to open a new terminal with a script, but rather than showing it as a popup, I want to make it as the first available selection on Alt-Tab switching.

Comment: To be clear, your objective is to open the window below all other windows and become the first in queue of your ALT+TAB List?